# How do you escape a forward slash in xpath?

Tags: xpath

Some tags were flattened into text and I'm trying to find them so we can fix them.

```
<p>Random Paragraph &lt;list-type&gt;optional&lt;/list-type&gt;</p>
<p>Equation: 5 &gt; 3 + 1</p>
```

I want to include the / so I don't have to sift through a bunch of equations with actual less than or greater than signs as in the second paragraph - fairly common in this dataset.

This doesn't work and I can find nothing about actually escaping or literal /

```
//text()[matches(., "&lt;/")]
```

*Yes, I saw the post with nearly the exact same title - the solution was something about namespaces and not useful.*

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is with the `&lt;` not with the slash.

You haven't said what the host language for your XPath expression is. When XPath is embedded in XML, you need to use XML escaping conventions, so `<` is written as `&lt;`, newline is written as `&#x0a;`. If XPath is embedded in (say) Java, you need to use Java escaping conventions so newline is written as `\n` but `<` is written (unescaped) as `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use single quotes.

```
//text()[matches(.,'&lt;/')]
```

I'd tried that before and it spit out errors, must have had something else wrong.